# Integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2} {\sin x \cos x \sqrt{\tan x} \ln{\tan x} \,dx}$

Tags: integration

Challenge question: solve $$\int_0^{\pi/2} {\sin x \cos x \sqrt{\tan x} \ln{\tan x} \,dx}$$

It's a generalization of a recent Math.SE question, but how would one normally approach it?

Comment: To which math.se question are you referencing?

Comment: i have only found a numerical value of your integral $$0.2383627095847316199842751304939977634136721384754172600021618182991202279207338258104065665273398798$$

Comment: @user190080 : [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076791/alternative-method-of-solving-int-0-pi-2-sin2x-ln-tan-x-dx) by JohnChessant. He has a function $I(a)$, and he is asking for $I(2)$. I simply posed $I(4)$ (this question).

Comment: @THA I have been summoned. :D Yes, $I(4)$ is equivalent to the integral in this question, and by my formula the answer is $\frac{1}{16}\pi\left(4−\pi\right)\sqrt{2}$ (talk of funny answers ;) ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
\sqrt{\tan x}=t,\quad x=\arctan (t^2),\quad dx=\frac{2t\:dt}{1+t^4},
$$ one gets

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2} {\sin x \cos x \sqrt{\tan x} \ln{\tan x} \,dx}=\int_0^\infty \frac{4t^4\ln t}{\left(1+t^4\right)^2}\:dt=\frac{\pi  \sqrt{2}}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2\sqrt{2}}{16}. \tag1
> $$

---

*Addendum*. One may recall [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968756/calculating-int-0-infty-frac1x-alpha-frac11x-rm-dx)
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\alpha}{1+x}\:dx=-\frac{\pi}{\sin \alpha \pi}, \quad -1<\alpha<0, \tag2
$$ giving, with an integration by parts, 
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\alpha}{(1+x)^2}\:dx=\frac{\alpha \pi}{\sin \alpha \pi}, \quad -1<\alpha<1 \tag3
$$ differentiating $(3)$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\alpha\ln x}{(1+x)^2}\:dx=\frac{\pi}{\sin \alpha \pi}-\frac{\pi^2\alpha \cos \alpha \pi}{\sin^2 \alpha \pi}, \quad -1<\alpha<1, \tag4
$$ then putting $x=t^4$, $\alpha=\frac14$ gives $(1)$.

Comment: What is the method for evaluating the last integral?

Comment: Did you use integration by parts in the end? If yes, Could you please explain how did u evaluate $\int{\frac{4t^4}{(1+t^4)^2}dt}$

Comment: @ShreyasS did you forget the log in your comment ?

Comment: @OlivierOloa What is IPP ?Am I dumb ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I assumed he has integrated by parts, taking $lnt$ as the first function

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I've edited my hint. Thanks.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thank you very much. Happy new year to you.

Comment: +1 Happy new year all! And it appears there is no other way to do it; I asked the [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076791/alternative-method-of-solving-int-0-pi-2-sin2x-ln-tan-x-dx) that OP referenced; you can check that my formula was essentially equivalent to that of @OlivierOloa.

Comment: @John Chessant Thank you very much. Happy new year to all!

Answer (score 0):

Write $\ln\tan x=\ln\sin x-\ln\cos x$, replace $\sqrt{\tan x}$ also, and do the integral of the two summands separately.  For the first summand put $u=\sin x$ and integrate by parts. For the second summand put $u=\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $$\tan(x)\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin^2(x)=\frac{\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$ and putting $t=\tan(x)$, we get

$$I=\int_0^{+\infty}t^{\frac{3}{2}}dt=+\infty.$$

Comment: There was nothing modified that could have modified the question's meaning. In fact, the only edit was to include \int in the dollar signs.

Comment: If you want to delete your answer, you are free to do so.  The question now is, as all long, not changed.